# How to send custom filter parameters when loading a store in ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, filter, extjs4, upgrade, extjs6

**In ExtJs 4**, it was possible to have a JsonStore configured with `remoteFilter: false` and then send parameters to the server that allow to still filter on the server, like this:

```
store.load({
    filters: [{property: 'state', value: 5}]
})
```

This is documented [for Extjs 4.2.2](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) "`options`: config object, passed into the Ext.data.Operation object before loading."

**The purpose** of this is to load a subset of rows into the store (e.g. all records the user has access to) and allow local filtering (e.g. text search on certain columns).

**In ExtJs 6.2**, this no longer works. Only the properties `scope` and `callback` are [documented](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.JsonStore.html#method-load) as parameters for `store.load`, and using this feature in ExtJs 6.2 gives a fatal error: `filter.getFilterFn() is not a function in ext/packages/core/src/data/proxy/Server.js on line 389`

How can I reproduce a similar behavior in ExtJs 6.2 and send extra parameters just for one `store.load` call ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

```
 store.load({
     params: {
         state: 5
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

The strict equivalent of ExtJs 4's

```
store.load({
    filters: [{property: 'state', value: 5}]
})
```

is the following in ExtJs 6:

```
store.load({
    params: {
        filter: Ext.encode([{property: 'state', value: 5}])
    } 
})
```